# How to save an Array with angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose

I'm new with the mean stack and I'm building a phonebook system. Each person can have more than one phone number and I what to be able to save it to the model hereunder. I'm able to save it when I'm using postman as following:

Postman

```
key:phones[1][type]
value:"mobile"

key:phones[1][number]
value:"123-123-1234"

key:phones[2][type]
value:"home"

key:phones[2][number]
value:"987-987-9876"
```

Schema

```
const PhonesSchema = new Schema({
  type: { type: String},
  number: { type: String} 
});
const PersonSchema = new Schema({
    first_name: { type: String},
    last_name: { type: String},
    email: { type: String, unique: true},
    phones: [PhonesSchema]
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);
```

my issue came when I try to achieve it with angular... I'm able to do it for 1 phone number but not when I want to add more then one...  when I trying to pass person.phones[$index][type] it's not working neither....

```
<form ng-submit="save(person)">
  <fieldset data-ng-repeat="Phonefield in Phonefields track by $index">
    <select name="type[$index]" ng-model="person.phones.type" class="form-control">
      <option>Mobile </option>
      <option>Home </option>
      <option>Urgence</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone" name="number[$index]" ng-model="person.phones.number" class="form-control">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removePhonefield()">-</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addNewPhonefield()">Add fields</button>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save($index, person)">Create</button>
</form>
```

My phone fields are added dynamically using this code (works well)

```
$scope.Phonefields = [{id: '0'}];

$scope.addNewPhonefield = function() {
  var newItemNo = $scope.Phonefields.length+1;
  $scope.Phonefields.push({'id':newItemNo});
};

$scope.removePhonefield = function() {
var lastItem = $scope.Phonefields.length-1;
$scope.Phonefields.splice(lastItem);
};
```

this is my save function

```
 $scope.save = function(index,person) {
  $http.post('http://localhost:3001/api/person', person)

    .then(function(response) {

      $scope.persons.push(response.data);

    });
```

How can I convert the postman value I passed but within Angular?
    key:phones[1][type]
    value:"mobile"

Thanks everyone

Comment: - what is the output of `person` in that save function? Also, check the request headers, it should tell you if you're sending those other phone numbers over or not.

Comment: Also, your ng-model is set to `ng-model="person.phones.type"`.. Thats not going to work. It will need to be `person.phones[$index].type`, or similar... I'd imagine that is your issue. You're trying to use the same model for multiple inputs.

Comment: If I'm entering only 1 number it works (saw in the request header) but more than that, nothing is transferred. When I used person.phones[$index].type.... same results... nothing...

Comment: are you getting any console errors? for something like person.phones[$index].type to work, the person.phones[$index] object would need to exist.

Comment: the phones entry look like phones:[]

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue base on this demo

https://coderwall.com/p/r7bl4w/ng-repeat-index-for-a-form-field-array-ie-add-new-option

and at the end, I copy my new array inside the empty one, enjoy!